# Data is not being retrieved sqlite3 Python

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, rfid

So I am trying to retrieve all the users IDs from my sqlite3 database. I have a tkinter gui with a check-in `Button`when the user clicks the button they are prompted to scan their tag(rfid). I am trying to compare the tag id once the tag is scanned to all of the userIDs in the database and check if the two match. If they do match I am trying to print *User Verified* if the tag does not match one of the userID in the table I am trying to print *No user exist,Denied*

```
#sqlite3 table structure 
Table: 
    Users ->
         name    UserID
        {joe}   {d33sda}
        {moe}   {eg2q5n}
```

My issue is the `else` statement in the `checker()` function keeps getting thrown. I think the data is not being retrieved from the database or possibly the variable `r` is empty .The UID Im testing is the only entry in the table and does match the tag id so there is no reason for it to throw the else statement, any thoughts?

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3 as sql
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

global r
global uid_tag
def chk():
    Database = sql.connect('MedaDataBase.db')
    # cursor
    c= Database.cursor()

    #Query uid database
    c.execute("SELECT*, userID FROM Users ")

    #Fetch all uids from Database
    r= c.fetchall()

    if r:
        #Getting user uid from tag 
        id,uid_tag = reader.read()
        print(uid_tag)
        checker()

def checker():
    global uid_tag
    global r
    for x in r:
        #If userId from tag is in the database 
        if uid_tag == x:

            print("User Verified")
        else:
            print("Denied")    
            Database.commit()
            Database.close()
```

Comment: `r` and `uid_tag` are local variables in `chk()` function and cannot be accessed in `checker()` function.  Better pass them to `checker()` like `checker(r, uid_tag)` and redefine `checker()` to accept arguments: `def checker(r, uid_tag):`.  However, suggest not to select all records from `Users` table, just select record with `UserID` equals to `uid_tag`.

Comment: @tibaH_lluN You know that `x` will be a tuple of results right? So if `uid_tag == x:` will be false as `uid_tag` is not equal to (...,....,...), Myabe try `x[0]` or `x[1]` or something?

Comment: @acw1668 Okay Ill give that a try. Yeah that would be more efficient.